# Why Hibernate 5.0.6 release package does not contain transaction implementation jar?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-5.x

I have a code like that:

```
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final StandardServiceRegistry registry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                .configure().build();
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = null;
        try {
            sessionFactory = new MetadataSources(registry).buildMetadata()
                    .buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.destroy(registry);
        }

        if (sessionFactory != null) {
            StudentInfo studentInfo = new StudentInfo();
            studentInfo.setRollNo(1);
            studentInfo.setName("Dmytro");

            Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
            session.beginTransaction();

            session.save(studentInfo);

            session.getTransaction().commit();
            session.close();
            sessionFactory.close();
            StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.destroy(registry);
        }
    }
}
```

It throws an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/transaction/SystemException
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:274)
```

I read that I should add transaction API jar from required folder to the claspath. However, Hibernate 5.0.6 release package does not contain it.
[image]

Should I add transaction API implementation manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it is a problem of Hibernate 5.0.6 release. There is no need to manually add `transaction-api-1.1.jar` for Hibernate 5.0.3 release.

To add required jar

for Maven

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
      <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
      <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

for Gradle build

```
compile group: 'javax.transaction', name: 'transaction-api', version: '1.1'
```

manual download

http://central.maven.org/maven2/javax/transaction/transaction-api/1.1/transaction-api-1.1.jar

**Update**

It is not a bug, it is a feature.

> Due to the proliferation of JTA artifacts under various GAVs, Hibernate exporting one as a transitive dependency can cause problems in environments where another GAV is used.
>   This should be marked as provided to make sure people don't get it on classpath without explicitly asking for it.

From there

[Make JTA a provided (non-transitive) dependency](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-10178)

**Update 2**

It was a bug anyway. It is not need to provide `transaction-api-1.1.jar` in the dependences for Hibernate 5.0.7.

> Hibernate exposes javax.transaction.Synchronization from a public API. Whether you use JTA or not, you can register a JTA Synchronization for transaction callbacks. So the JTA spec jar is a non-optional dependency. Allowing this to become non-transitive was a mistake which will be reverted: see [HHH-10307](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-10307)

Answer (score 0):

To use Hibernate Transaction API, you would obtain the org.hibernate.Transaction from the Session.
See this link : 
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/userGuide/en-US/html_single/#transactions-api

Comment: I included full Java class code example. As you see I begin transaction and close it, however Java throws an error earlier in the code.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with *v.ladynev* answer. Release 5.0.3 contains transaction API implementation jar, however, release 5.0.6 does not.

**Screenshots from maven repository**

Core Hibernate O/RM Functionality » 5.0.3.Final dependencies:
[image]

Core Hibernate O/RM Functionality » 5.0.6.Final dependencies:
[image]

It seems that transaction API is not used in some applications, so if you need it you can add it manually.